# How to use single input for multiple dependent input task

Tags: sbt

I have an issue that I have been working on for about two days straight with no luck.  I have two task, package and deploy that both change depending on the environment being deployed to.  I am using the sbt-native-packager plugin for packaging and the sbt-deploy-ssh for deployment.

My package task gets called by an inputTask like so: bundle "env"

```
lazy val setEnv : Def.Initialize[InputTask[String]] = Def.inputTask {
  sbt.Def.spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed(0)
}

lazy val configure : Def.Initialize[InputTask[String]] = Def.inputTask {
val env = setEnv.evaluated
  writeConfig(env)
  env
}

lazy val bundle = inputKey[Unit]("bundles project for specific env")
bundle := configure.parsed.flatMap { _ =>
  (packageBin in config("universal")).taskValue
}.value
```

My deploy task gets called by an inputTask like so: deployTo "env"

```
val deployTo = inputKey[Unit]("Deploys to specific env")
deployTo := Def.inputTaskDyn {
  val args = sbt.Def.spaceDelimited("<args>").parsed
  deployWithDynamicServers(getServers(args(0)))
}.evaluated

def deployWithDynamicServers(servers: Seq[String]) = Def.taskDyn {
  deploySsh.toTaks(" " + servers.mkString(" "))
}
```

I can run both of these individually, but I want the deploy task to be dependent on the package task.  What I want to be able to do is run deployTo  and have the supplied env passed to the package task as well.

So far I haven't had much luck because I keep getting "Illegal Dynamic reference errors" even though both the package and deploy task are Def.inputTaksDyn

Answer (score 0):

[Your case is described here.](https://github.com/shmishleniy/sbt-deploy-ssh/blob/master/README.md#artifacts)

Just add your env to the `deployConfigs`

```
deployConfigs ++= Seq(
    ServerConfig("env", "169.254.0.2")
)
```

add the artifact to the `deployArtifacts`

```
deployArtifacts ++= Seq(
    ArtifactSSH((packageBin in config("universal")).value, "/tmp/")
)
```

and start deploy with `deploySsh`.

```
deploySsh yourServerName1 yourServerName2 ...
```